# A Grasslands Planet

Tags: science-based, planets

I was wondering if a planet's main biome could be Grasslands. Such planet can even exist? Is it possible to have a planet who's mostly Grasslands with other biomes being the minority?

Comment: Suggest this is a duplicate of https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/222213/is-a-rainforest-or-any-single-biome-planet-feasible

Comment: Hi Dakka! I think that the query Kerr Avon linked you to answers your question here. I'm going to vote to close your question for the suggested reason. If you think I'm incorrect, or that the linked question doesn't address what you're after, please edit your question so that it is essentially distinct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a rainforest (or any single-biome) planet feasible](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/222213/is-a-rainforest-or-any-single-biome-planet-feasible)

Comment: **I'm going to suggest that the linked Q claimed to be a duplicate... *isn't.*** If Dakka was asking if grasslands could be the *only* biome, then it would be a duplicate. But as the primary biome? Arctic and desert biomes are *already in the minority,* so what we're really asking is, is it possible during a planet's history *to not have substantial forest, jungle, or marine biomes?* Simplistically, what comes first, grass or trees? I think that's a valid question not at all answered by the linked question.

Comment: Now, @Dakka, having said that, you might want to set your expectations. You need rainfall to have grasslands as your primary *land-based* biome. That means oceans and lakes.... I can't predict this issue off the top of my head, but I suspect that to have grasslands be the primary *land-based* biome you'll need more water than you have land, which will make the marine biome the primary. My question to you, does that matter? Please [edit] your post with the answer. Cheers!

Comment: Should this be a permanent situation or a phase in the development of the planet's biosphere? The first land plants on Earth were small, and it took time before they evolved strong lignin trunks that allowed trees to grow high. Until then, there were grasses.

Answer (score 1):

A grass biome requires a few external elements. The native prairies of North America had a wide range of different grasses, flowering plants, and other plants besides. The forces that kept it a prairie were the lower rainfall than the forests further east, frequent fires to keep the trees down, and rotating herds of grazing animals. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prairie Without the fires, trees will take over much of the prairie (see how juniper and mesquite are taking over much of Texas prairie without the periodic fires).

Grasses are competitive. Some will grow quite tall. On the North American prairie, big blue stem will grow 6 feet tall with shoots over 9 feet. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tallgrass_prairie) Bamboo (a grass) grows even taller.

Different grasses fit different niches. Those that grow in disturbed areas will have shallow roots. Those that grow in dryer areas can have roots going over 6 feet deep. Fire adapted grasses have their heart underground so that they survive a quick grass fire.

In short, there won't be a single grass biome. There could be multiple grass biomes. You also need the large herbivores and fire. You need a reason why frequent fire happens. The Wikipedia article on prairies suggests that humans set many of the fires that made the prairies happen.

Comment: You might not be looking at this from the perspective of the OP, who doesn't have degrees in biology or planetary ecology. If you think more in terms of the card game [ecologies](https://www.etsy.com/listing/781597126/ecologies-card-game-gameplay-inspired-by), you'll be closer to what the OP is asking. In otherwords, splitting grassland biomes into their constituent biomes is splitting the hair too thin to reasonably answer the OP's question, even with the [tag:science-based] tag.

Comment: To get frequent forest fires, I think that an atmosphere with a high oxygen concentration could suffice: on earth it is thought that we reached 35% $O_2$ just prior to the Permian extinction, so there's no big problem there. Of course, if the planet doesn't have oceans or another efficient carbon sink, it could be difficult to have a consistent scenario for such a high $O_2$ concentration (You could maybe posit a planet homogeneously covered in peat, but I don't know whether such a soil could really accommodate 'grasslands', nor is the hydrology picture of such a planet clear to me).